# How can I recreate Schema.rb (after deleting) in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, schema, schema.rb

I deleted my Schema.rb by mistake (sort of) and I can't seem to be able to regenerate it into db/ by using rake db:dump, I don't really know what to do at this point.

Some suggested
rake db:dump:all
rake db:create:all
rake db:migrate

Nothing worked. Please help!

Comment: Sorry, I meant db:drop:all not dump

Comment: Is your project under some source control, like git?

Answer (score 9):

Try running `bundle exec rake db:schema:dump`.

Refer to [Active Record Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) for more info.

Comment: This should work. Just as an aside, you may not be required to use `bundle exec` depending on where you have gems installed and how your path is setup.

Comment: Nothing happened :( When I put that in, it just returned a new line. I don't really know what to do. This happened to me before, and I just used the 3 lines that I put up above with drop:all, create:all, and migrate. But it's no longer working.

Comment: Try running `bundle exec rake db:schema:dump --trace`. Notice the extra `--trace` option and see what all tasks are being run.

Answer (score 3):

You could try

`rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`

That should do it.   If you're not getting any errors and the schema file is not being regenerated, then something is potentially wacky with your local environment.